# Find if a point (latitude, longitude) is within OpenStreetMaps "way" (area)

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I have a list of longitude and latitude points for various houses, offices, etc.  I am trying to split them up to determine if they are inside a certain [Way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) or not.  I don't want to use the old "centre point" of an area and then radius value as that is not accurate enough.

So for example if I had 4 locations in an Way like "Richmond Upon Thames" that looks like this: [image]

It should return just point B and C.  Is this possible using Open Street Maps API?

Comment: "Is this possible using Open Street Maps API?" No. The OSM API is mainly an *editing* API and not designed to perform arbitrary spatial calculations.

Comment: @scai Ah I see.  Does this mean I'll need to first of all download all the spatial data for the Way area and then use some of my own code to calculate if a long/lat point is or isn't in a Way area?

Comment: The coordinates of the way should be sufficient to determine whether the  points are inside or outside. No additional data is needed.

Comment: I see.  I guess the only issue I have then is trying to find a function that can calculate "isInsideWay" function.  I see there are plenty of answers of how to do that but none if the lat and long values have both negative and positive points.

Comment: I guess you should ask a new question about your new issue, preferably at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like Java, you could load the way as a Polygon and use the JTS (Java Topology Suite) library, or the AWT library to compute whether your points are inside or not.

[Here](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/blob/5.0.14/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/atlas/geography/Polygon.java#L157-L192) is an example of how the [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/5.0.14) library uses a combination of both in that specific case. For you it would look like this:

1. Convert each latitude/longitude pair of the Way to a `Location` object
2. Add each `Location` to a List and create a new Polygon with it
3. Call the `Polygon.fullyGeometricallyEncloses(Location)` method on that `Polygon` with each of the points of interest you have

The Atlas library is [available in Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openstreetmap/atlas/atlas/) for you to download.